# Передача данных между активити

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Мне нужно сделать приложение со следующей логикой: нажимаю кнопку "открыть" (в верхней части) -> открывается галерея, выбирается изображение и вставляется посреди экрана;
внизу есть кнопка "поехали" -> открывается новая активити, в которой вставлено это изображение.

Суть проблемы: не могу понять ка передать расположение (contentUri) из первой активити во вторую, так как это расположение я получаю внутри переопределённого  onActivityResult(). То есть расположение определяется внутри onActivityResult(), а переход в новую активити происходит при нажатии кнопки, на которой весит отдельная функция newAct(). 
Я смог произвести запуск новой активити и соответственно передачу данных с помощью putExtra только прямо из onActivityResult() (выбрал картинку и сразу переход в новую актвити), но тогда кнока "процесс" не задействуется. 
Пытался сделать глобальный intent, но приложение крашится

Comment: Что вам мешает объявить локальную переменную с `uri`, в `onActivityResult()` присваивать ей значение, а в кнопке для перехода использовать эту переменную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявите в вашей активити, где вы обрабатываете `onActivityResult()`, поле `uri`, которое вы проинициализируете в этом методе. А затем, при нажатии кнопки, у вас будет доступ к `uri`, т.к. оно лежит в поле. Однако, не забудьте добавить проверку, т.к. если нажать на кнопку до того, как вы проинициализируете поле, вместо нужного `uri` будет передан `null` (а в случае с Kotlin, если использовать `lateinit` — получите исключение; либо также можете использовать `Uri?` тип и проверять на `null`, чтобы узнать, было ли поле проинициализировано; а также с последней версии Kotlin можно проверить, было ли проинициализировано `lateinit`-поле).

```
class MyActivity : Activity() {

    private lateinit var uri: Uri
    private lateinit var button: Button

    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        button = findViewById<View>(R.id.my_button) as Button

        button.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent().putExtra("uri", uri.toString()))
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

            uri = // получите uri
    }
}
```